# Immediately targeted serial un-upvotes

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

Not one day back and someone targets me for abuse.

[image]

What is being done about this?

Comment: Yes they are. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199946/are-unupvotes-serial-voting/199952#199952

Comment: I stand corrected but there is nothing anyone here can do about it. You would have to contact the CM's. They can take the appropriate action if they deem it necessary.

Comment: They're still not downvotes. Serial voting, maybe; serial *down*votes, no. Unfortunately, I believe serial unupvotes aren't caught by the automatic algorithm. Nor can mods reverse votes, so you'll have to ask a CM directly. Not sure what you hope to accomplish by posting to meta.

Comment: @Randal'Thor serial un-upvoting "certainly falls under serial voting" and is against SE policy,  e.g. see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199952/178179

Answer (score 2):

As brought up in the comments, it is hard to determine what *should* be done about this, but as is, there probably isn't anything being activley done. There is no *down*voting, here; what you have experienced is a serial *unup*voting. This has been brought up, in meta; and we have arrived at the following conclussion, [via the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199946/are-unupvotes-serial-voting/199952#199952):

- Unupvoting *is* a form of serial voting, and is completely against the rules of Stack Exchange.
- The scripts in charge of reversing these serial upvotes do *not* consider unupvotes.

---

In terms of what *can* be done; you *could* raise this with one of the community moderators, by accessing the [contact us](https://movies.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page. This link will direct your communication to people that actually *can* do something about this. However, there are further observations that you may want to consider:

- All four questions were previously edited for legitimate reason. As such, we can determine that a user has not gone to explicit malicious intent to remove their votes from your questions.
- As such, we *assume* that a single user has gone to effort to serial unupvote you. It is entirely possible (though, in my opinion, implausible) that a user has been made aware of these edits, and already previously expressed intent to remove their upvotes; where as these votes may have previously been locked in. It is also possible that these votes have come from separate users, who in coincidentally have noticed that these answers had since been edited, giving them a window to undo their votes.
- It is clear you want something done; but *what* do you want done? It is worth addressing the fact that if this user is removed for said behaviour, it is entirely possible that their votes will be removed, too. Ergo, you will not get your votes back, and you might just as easily lose additional votes.

Comment: 4 separate un-upvotes in the span of 1 minute, along with the others prior to this date of the same type of abuse. No such coincidence.

Comment: @cde, as I said, it is certainly *possible*, but *implausible*.